# complex if condition powershell

Tags: powershell, filtering

I want to create  a  condition that validates   3 things   in powershell.

I'm tryign the  following:  lets  say  I  have a bunch of  AD   users with a  mismatch on  userPrincipalName  and  Mail fields, and some  dont have the  mail filed populated.  i'm trying to build  a condition that checks   1 . mail and  upn domains  to  match  and  2  to check if  its the  correct  domain.

I created  2  simple functions   i  to split the either  UPN or  Mail field  by   "@domain.com" and im trying to build  a second  function ta checks  multiple  conditions  and  return  a  case

Is this  a valid condition? `if($upn -and $mail -eq $cdomain){ #<<<<-- ---is  this  a valid condition?`

lets  say  i got  3 users Objects in AD with the  th the  following  info:

```
victor reyes
UPN =  victor.reyes@gmail.com
mail = victor.reyes@gmail.com


pablo reyes 
UPN = pablo.reyes@correctdomain.com
mail = pablo.reyes@gmail.com

robert reyes
UPN =  roberto.reyes@CorrectDomain.com
mail = ""
```

in the case of  victor  reyes     both  domains are the  same but  are  incorrect  (supposed to be  correctdomain.com)

pablo reyes  has a mixup of  domains  and  need to check  what  the corec one  is

and  robert reyes does  not  have  a  mail  but dos have a  correct  upn  how could  i go about  creating a  condition that could  generate  a  case  per  everyone  of these conditions ?

Sorry i  cant  seem to find  the correct  words  for  what i want to do.   Please  see example bellow

Example:

```
function GetDomain{
    param (
        $Domain
    )

    $output = $domain.Split("@")
    return $output[1]
}

function GetCase {
    param (
        $UPNDomain,
        $MailDomain
    )
    $cdomain = "@correctdomain.com"
    $upn = GetDomain $UPNDomain
    $mail =  GetDomain $MailDomain

    # if  $upn and  $mail  are  equals   and   are equals  to $cdomain  return Case 1
    if($upn -and $mail -eq $cdomain){ #<<<<-- ---is  this  a valid condition?
        return Case1
        }
    #if  $upn and $mail are not equals,  and  $upn is  equal to $cdomain  return Case2 
    elseif(){return Case2}
    #if $upn  and $mail are not equals, and  $mail is equal to $cdomain return Case3
    elseif(){return Case3}
    
    etc 

}
```

Comment: It should be `if($upn -eq $cdomain -and $mail -eq $cdomain)`

Comment: what about  if  i  want  to check  to check if  $upn  and   $mail  are the  same  something like   this  `if( upn == mail && upn == cdomain &&  mail==cdomain){}`

Comment: The operator for equality is `-eq`. If you want to check if `$upn` is equal to `$mail` you use `if($upn -eq $mail)` ?! If you want to combine more than one condition you connect each complete comparison with an `-and` or `-or`

Comment: You may (re-)read the help [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2). You should read it completely including examples to learn how to use it. ;-)

Comment: I think the order of your conditions is off, you should be checking first if they're valid addresses, then check if they both match, then check if they both match with the expected domain imo

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would personally approach it, definitely would use the [`MailAddress` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=net-6.0) to check if they're valid email addresses, and by doing so, there would be no need for the `GetDomain` function.

Hopefully the inline comments helps you understand the logic.

```
function Get-Case {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter()]
        [string] $UPNDomain,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $MailDomain,

        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Domain
    )

    end {
        $upn  = $UPNDomain -as [mailaddress]
        $mail = $MailDomain -as [mailaddress]

        # check if both parameters are valid email addresses
        if(-not $upn -or -not $mail) {
            # one of them or both are not valid
            return 'case0'
        }

        # check if the upn and mail Domain match,
        if($upn.Host -ne $mail.Host) {
            # if they don't, no need to keep checking
            return 'case1'
        }

        # here we assume they're the same,
        # check if their Domain is the same as `$Domain`
        if($upn.Host -eq $Domain) {
            # mail and upn Domain are the same and Domain matches both
            return 'case2'
        }

        # if above was not true, then their Domain is incorrect
        return 'case3'
    }
}

# case2: both mails Domain match and they also match with expected Domain
Get-Case victor.reyes@gmail.com victor.reyes@gmail.com -Domain gmail.com
# case1: mails Domain don't match
Get-Case pablo.reyes@correctdomain.com pablo.reyes@gmail.com -Domain correctdomain.com
# case0: one of the arguments is not a valid mail
Get-Case roberto.reyes@CorrectDomain.com '' -Domain correctdomain.com
```